# Using Newton's Method in Python, no error messages but does not print/plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use Newton's method to approximate the root for the Colebrook equation with Python. Currently the code gives no error but also does not print/plot. I understand this could be an individual case and thanks for all the help in advance!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xdZQ.jpg)

```
numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Define Variables, k=e/D, E+04<=x=Re<=E+07
k=0.0001

#Define Colebrook function, f=x=independent variable
def f(x):
    return -0.86*(np.log(( 2.51/(Re*np.sqrt(x))) + ( k/3.7))) - (1/np.sqrt(x))

#Define derivative function by definition & approximation
def derivative(f,x,h):
    return (f(x + h) - f(x))/h

#Newton's method approximation with initial gussed x value
x=0.01
for Re in range (10^4,10^7, 10000):
    m=derivative(f,x,h=0.01)
    b=f(x)-m*x #y=mx+b
    newx=-b/m #new x value determined by the tangent line
    if abs(g(newx))<= (1/10000000000):
        print ('root =' + newx)
    else:
        x=newx

#plot
for Re in range (10^4, 10^7,10000):
    x=newx
    plt.plot (f(x))
```

I already know the root I'm looking for is approx. 0.03.

Comment: not sure how this works, but you are just returning stuff currently, never actually calling print() on one of the functions that returns. That's why. print(f(x)) will give you that value.

Comment: You appear to want to call `plot()` 1000 times identically

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious problem:

```
range (10^4,10^7, 10000)
```

gives no output. You should look up the definition of `range`: the third input is the step size, not the number of steps; and I suppose you wanted to use "power", `10**4`, `10**7`. The `^` symbol is bitwise XOR.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Already changed that but still no error/plot/print tho

Comment: Is it running??

Comment: Used both jupyter notebook and spider, both ran and showed nothing

Comment: OK, but did it finish? The print statement only executes under a given condition, maybe that condition isn't reached. The plot won't happen with the range you give for the same reason as the text of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues:

- As mdurant pointed out, your range needs some proper rewriting.
- Your first loop calls a `g(x)` function you don't have defined anywhere.
- Even after that though, your second loop is saying "Let x be xnew, then add f(x) to the plot, and repeat that many times (without ever changing the value of x)".
- Also, I think plt.plot() just adds data to the plot.  You need plt.show() to see the graph.  You may also want to define your plots axes, colors, etc.  Some sample scripts using matplotlib can show you the syntax.